# Using sed to replace a pattern between curly braces where line immediately before the opening curly brace has a known word

Tags: awk, sed, replace, pattern-matching, openfoam

I would like to change:

```
inlet
{
    type    patch;
    ...
}
outlet
{
        type  patch;
}
```

to

```
inlet
{
    type    wall;
    ...
}
outlet
{
        type  patch;
}
```

As a first attempt to achieve this, I tried to limit the range between inlet and outlet and replace "patch" with wall.

```
echo "inlet { patch } outlet" | sed "/^\(inlet [^ ]*\) .* \([^ ]*\)$/s//\1 wall \2/"
```

which gave output :

```
inlet { wall outlet
```

The last curly bracket is missing.

```
echo "inlet {patch} outlet {patch}"| sed "/inlet/,/outlet/{s/patch/wall/}"
```

gave output :

```
inlet {wall} outlet {patch}
```

However, I need to make sure that the "patch" that is replaced by wall shall have a "type" in the same line. It is this part I need to resolve now.

Comment: `'s/[img:.*]/[img]/g'` ??? This is a random command that have nothing to do here AFAIK

Comment: @GillesQuénot, yes. I started with this command to solve this

Comment: please update the question with your actual code (not a link to some other Q&A) and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: your code is likely to fail in various conditions. eg. nested braces; braces inside comments/regex/strings; with macros/includes/conditionals, etc, (cf. https://doc.cfd.direct/openfoam/user-guide-v11/basic-file-format ). you'd be better off refactoring your configs so that the parts to be changed are macros or includes, for example, so that you don't have to write your own parser for the format

Comment: Do you specifically want to replace the string `patch` but not change any other string if it was in that location, or do you want to change any string that's inside `inlet` at the end of a line that starts with `type`?

Comment: @jhnc Thanks for pointing out that. Right now, this work but as you said, it can fail easily. Includes can improve the stability. Thanks

Comment: @EdMorton My upstream workflow kind of ensure that only patch will appear in that location. So, I can safely replace patch, I guess. But below the line with type, there could be patch, before }, which I do not want to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^inlet$/{n;/^\{$/{:a;N;/^\}$/M!ba;s/^(\s+type\s+)\S+/\1wall;/M}}' file
```

Search for line containing `inlet` only.

Print it and fetch the next line.

If that line contains only `{`, fetch subsequent lines until one containing only `}`.

Now substitute a line beginning and separated by white space, two words: the first being `type` and then replace the second word by `wall;`.

N.B. The use of the `M` flag in both regexp and the substitution commands, that bound the regexp by line i.e. the anchors respect the `^` and `$` anchors, in a multiline string.

Answer (score 1):

Using any POSIX awk, if you want to replace any string in that position:

```
$ awk '
    /^[[:alpha:]]/ { f = ($1 == "inlet") }
    f && ($1 == "type") { sub(/[^[:space:]]+;$/,""); $0=$0 "wall;" }
    { print }
' file
inlet
{
    type    wall;
    ...
}
outlet
{
        type  patch;
}
```

or if you only want to replace `patch` specifically then change the 2nd line of the script to:

```
f && ($1 == "type") && ($2 == "patch;") { sub(/[^[:space:]]+;$/,""); $0=$0 "wall;" }
```

and if there could be spaces before or after the last `;` on the line:

```
f && ($1 == "type") && ($2 ~ /^patch;?$/) { sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*$/,""); $0=$0 "wall;" }
```